Blank swagger-ui page in spring boot webflux
I have a spring boot webflux application and I need to configure swagger-ui for it. I am deploying the application on aws lambda and also have an aws gateway API that I can use to access the swagger-ui page.
Swagger dependency:
implementation 'org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webflux-ui:2.5.0'
OpenAPI Configuration:
// Configuration for the swagger-ui.
@OpenAPIDefinition
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI usersMicroserviceOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(new Info().title("Buyur App API")
                        .description("API Description")
                        .version("1.0"));
    }
}

I also get SwaggerUIBundle and invalid or unexpected token errors in the browser console.
I have a rough idea that it might be related to the encoding of the response, but adding a filter did not fix the problem.
Encoding Filter:
@Configuration
public class EncodingFilter {

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public WebFilter utf8Filter() {
        return new WebFilter() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, WebFilterChain chain) {
                exchange.getResponse()
                        .getHeaders()
                        .setContentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                return chain.filter(exchange);
            }
        };
    }
}

Edit:
Here are the errors that I get in the browser console.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at swagger-ui-bundle.js:2:218114)


Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js:2:108540)


Uncaught ReferenceError: SwaggerUIBundle is not defined
at window.onload (swagger-initializer.js:5:3)

The starting part of the error in swagger-ui-bundle.js looks something like this:

var _=u(54552)({Ã:"A",Ã:"A",Ã:"A",Ã:"A",Ã:"A"

